# Was there supposed to be a treehouse in Frozen II?

Tags: disney, lego, toys, frozen, frozen-ii

The toy company LEGO has released a playset, *41164 Enchanted Treehouse*, based on Disney's Frozen II film. The set features a treehouse with a zipline and Arendelle-related insignia, possibly indicating that the treehouse is supposed to be a base for Arendelle's military. I have seen the film itself twice, and don't recall there being any treehouse at all, though the separate, included standing stones were present in the film, and the character dressed in green, Matthias, does appear in the film as a soldier of Arendelle.

Do we know the history of this treehouse? That is, is this solely a toy invention, or was this inspired by a treehouse that was removed from the script or film after merchandising development started?

[image: LEGO Frozen II set 41164 Enchanted Treehouse]

Comment: Elsa didn't have a magical jewellery box either; https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07NRT2CYF/ref=psdc_3228092011_t1_B07PZF1GQQ

Comment: Sometimes LEGO sets contain things not in the movie.  For example, one of the sets for "The Last Jedi" contained a weird spider walker that never made it in the film.  Often these are just for play purposes rather than any sort of canon.

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but unlike in a live action movie where a lot may end up on the cutting room floor, not giving toys time to change their design, an animation actually takes a lot longer than Lego production.  The pre-render of the entire movie could have been done before Lego started and they would have still had plenty of time make the toy.

Comment: [Lego - Least accurate sets ever](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/110719-least-accurate-sets-based-on-movies/)